# std::hash vs crc32

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11, хеширование

Какая функция используется для создания хэша в std::hash и насколько она предпочтительнее, чем обычный crc32? Предпочтениями являются меньшее число коллизий, более быстрый расчет. Основа - 32-х битная система. Выдержки из стандарта в качестве ответа не приветствуются.

Comment: @Softinaria, понятно, что  (судя по самостоятельно найденному ответу) Вы по сути хотели бы обсудить, а какая функция хэширования лучше (на примере сравнения, скажем с CRC32 (для затравки)). К сожалению, тут теперь похоже не те правила (и сложившийся контингент им в основном соответствует), чтобы задавать такие вопросы, ответы на которые неоднозначны, да еще и наверняка зависят от мнений... Так что, примите мои искренние соболезнования.

Comment: @avp да, я хотел обсудить что лучше. Разве это не следует даже из темы вопроса? И не для затравки я взял crc32 и std::hash. И то и другое возвращает обычное число. Поэтому и возникает вопрос, что лучше использовать для расчета контрольной суммы. Стандартное решение удобнее, но стандарт не оговаривает конкретной функции. Не факт, что она не изменится впоследствие. И если, скажем, например, клиент будет "старым" и будет проверять по данному хэшу есть ли такой же файл на "новом" сервере, то получится фигня. (это пример) В то же время, crc32 более проверен.

Comment: Что значит, более проверен? А murmur (bernstain, crap, ...), думаете нет?

Comment: @avp Ну само собой, что под фразой `более проверен` я не имел ввиду свойства самих алгоритмов. Я имел ввиду именно сам вариант использования. Именно тот факт, что функция, используемая в стандарте возможно будет меняться. И так ли это на самом деле покажет лишь время.

Comment: Кстати, почитал комментарии. Вас сильно беспокоит число коллизий? Если Вы их вообще допускаете (т.е. коллизия это нормальный для алгоритма случай), то несколько процентов коллизий обычно совершенно не влияют на общее время обработки. / Учтите, murmur такой быстрый только на системах, которые допускают невыровненный доступ к памяти (x86), на arm, например, он будет медленнее.

Comment: Да, функции могут меняться. Поэтому на практике поменьше смотрите на стандарты, побольше пишите своего.

Comment: @avp А как же "не изобретать велосипеды"?

Comment: Это пишут люди, которые сами изобрести ничего не могут -)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Основа - 32-х битная система.

Вы понимаете, что crc32 и разрядность вашей системы никак не соотносятся? crc32 использовался и в 16-битных ОС типа MS-DOS. И 32 - это просто размер итогового хэша в битах.

> Какая функция используется для создания хэша в std::hash

std::hash это не функция, а шаблон, поэтому для хэширования различных типов он будет использовать разные алгоритмы хэширования, например, `std::hash` для `int 1` [вернет](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38304877/5006740) `1`, поскольку хэш для числа - это само число.

Кроме того, вы не сказали, какую именно реализацию стандартной библиотеки C++ вы используете. В теории можно представить себе библиотеку, которая для всего хэширования использует crc32 (и работает очень плохо).

crc32 используется для небольших данных, зато быстрый. md5 в медленней, зато гораздо труднее нарваться на коллизию (32 бита < 128 бит в md5)

ответ на комментарии:

> Я соотносил crc32 с хэшем c++11, а он в свою очередь зависит от
>   битности оси. И для корректного сравнения они должны быть одной
>   разрядности

зависит от стандарта ISO, потом от разработчика компилятора.
как он реализует хэширование  - его собственное дело, если не прописано в стандарте, и да, именно std::hash зависит от разрядности системы, вы правы.

> The actual hash functions are implementation-dependent 
>   а это значит что и clang  и msvc и gcc и все остальные могут реализовать их по-разному.
>   Разве я спрашивал про md5 и его скорость? Он устарел. И там где мне
>   необходимы хэши с минимальными коллизиями я его не буду использовать.

вот это новость. md5 уязвим к намеренным атакам (вы можете создать коллизию специально), поэтому он устарел как криптографический хэш (спасибо @D-side за правку) , но как функция хэширования - нет.  (хорошее [сравнение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323046/5006740) md5/sha1)

дефолтная функция для  хэширования строк в gcc - MurmurHashUnaligned2

и вот вам абсолютно [прекрасное](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/145633/231059) сравнение различных алгоритмов хэширования

Comment: Как бы а Вы понимаете зачем я в принципе указал битность системы? Я вовсе не соотносил crc32 c битностью ОСи. Я соотносил crc32 с хэшем c++11, а он в свою очередь зависит от битности оси. И для корректного сравнения они должны быть одной разрядности.

Comment: Шаблон не считает хэш. Его расчитывает какая-то функция. Если используются несколько функций, то какие и в чем их преимущество/недостатки перед crc32. Или я не так поставил вопрос?

Comment: Я указал, что использую c++11 из gcc под линукс. А это всего-то или gcc-4.7 или gcc-4.8 Вы полагаете, что функция(и) хэширования в них разные?

Comment: Разве я спрашивал про md5 и его скорость? Он устарел. И там где мне необходимы хэши с минимальными коллизиями я его не буду использовать. Сравнение я хочу узнать по std::hash и crc32, так как они по сути выдают числа одной разрядности.

Comment: В общем - минус за ответ ради ответа.

Comment: @strangeqargo По поводу внесенной правки... Да. Алгоритм расчета хэша не стандартизирован, но он должен возвращать size_t. А это число, размер которого зависит от битности. Так что какой бы алгоритм не реализовывал разработчик компилятора - результатом будет число. На мой субъективный взгляд, если результатами хэша являются числа с одной разрядностью, то и вероятность коллизии будет одинакова.

Comment: @strangeqargo А вот скорость обработки будет конечно же зависить непосредственно от алгоритма. И здесь уже даже для того же crc32 могут быть различия. Ну например, если он будет предварительно рассчитывать таблицу, или она будет уже забита.

Comment: @strangeqargo Про md5 не по делу упомянули именно Вы. Я же в комментарии указал, что использовать не буду его использовать, если нужны будут хэши с минимальными коллизиями. Или Вы думаете что возможность преднамеренного создания коллизии не говорит о том, что этот алгоритм не дает нужного результата (минимальных коллизий при расчете хэша)?

Comment: @strangeqargo забираю минус, потому как в Вашем ответе уже появились и ссылка на тесты и название алгоритма. :)

Comment: @strangeqargo как то судя по тестам, приведенным также еще и Max ZS получается, что `murmurhash2` быстрее `crc32`, но проигрывает по числу коллизий. Мне всегда казалось, что алгоритм хэширования уж по чему, а по количеству коллизий должна бы быть лучше, чем контролька :(

Comment: в stdlib алгоритмы для быстрого хэширования. вам все-таки надо выбрать для ваших практических применений алгоритм и взять его реализацию, можете даже свою специализацию std::hash написать, наверное

Comment: @strangeqargo Да. Я понимаю. Для этого и был поставлен вопрос. Правда есть еще один при этом ньюанс. Хотелось бы использовать стандартную функцию, но, получается, что она как бы и не "стандартизирована". Т.е. если по факту ее использовать и на клиентах и на сервере, а со временем на сервере при перекомпиляции на обновленной оси она поменяется, то будет фигня.

Comment: не надо прилипать к стандарту, если вы реализуете клиент/сервер протокол, вы в любом случае должны описать там используемый алгоритм, а не стандарт языка. вдруг у вас клиент на go/swift/js/php а сервер на c++? и да, ничего страшного в использовании сторонних либ нет, посмотрите на бенчмарки и выберите лучшую для вас реализацию.

Comment: @strangeqargo ну я приводил клиент-сервер в качестве примера. И в таком случае вроде как действительно нельзя использовать стандартную функцию. Хотя это как-то и не кошерно получается. А под клиентом я имел ввиду приложение также написанное на c++. Ну а что касается других языков (например, того же js), то в любом случае нужно будет знать что за функцию использует сервер и описывать ее. Здесь как бы все понятно.\

Comment: *"устарел как функция для шифрования"* -- я вам чуть помогу с терминами, это называется ["криптографический хэш"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), к шифрованию он отношения всё-таки не имеет.

Comment: @D-side да, я в угаре редактирования слегка протупил, спасибо.

Comment: @strangeqargo я сравнил на массиве байт (можно сказать, что на строках) std::hash и crc32. Скорее всего, нельзя назвать мои тесты правильными, но std::hash действительно по скорости выигрывает crc32. Коллизии в целом по нулям у обоих. Только единожды crc32 выдал две коллизии при 100k строк длиной по 2к символов. При меньших "объемах" коллизий у обоих алгоритмов нет. Чем меньше длина строки, тем меньше разница в скорости. Если сравнивать слова и словосочетания, то они по скорости будут равны (что и логично, так как скорее всего основная затратка пойдет на разного рода иницилизации переменных).

Comment: @Softinaria я бы это  в ваш вопрос добавил постскриптумом (еще лучше если с кодом или ссылкой на него), полезно будет всем.

Comment: @strangeqargo Так-то оно так. Но человек скорее прочитает после заголовка и вопроса непосредственно отмеченный ответ, чем поскриптум. Более того, ввиду того, что в целом алгоритм расчета std::hash не стандартизирован и может быть изменет в последствие, то и результаты могут быть другими.

Answer (score 3):

Очевидно, ответ зависит от: типа данных, для которого вычисляется хеш, версии используемой стандартной библиотеки, разрядности и т.д. Если используешь libstdc++, то для std::string, попадем в функцию _Hash_bytes отсюда: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/hash_bytes.cc

Очевидно, это что-то совсем простое, выбранное из соображений производительности. Никак не CRC. Врядли у этого хеша есть имя.

Comment: Имя есть, указано в комментариях к коду: 'Based on public domain MurmurHashUnaligned2, by Austin // Appleby.  http://murmurhash.googlepages.com/'

Comment: Да, alexout прав, это MurmurHash2. Это следовало из ссылки в моем удаленном комментарии. Но вопрос так и остался открытым - что лучше? Не вижу в ответе ответа.

Comment: MurmurHash2 - быстрее (работает с блоками 32 или 64 бит). СRC -  проще реализуется аппаратно (в контексте c++ не актуально). Это вся разница.

Comment: @Chorkov http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4438660/Modern-C--in-embedded-systems---Part-1--Myth-and-Reality неплохая статья на тему

Answer (score 3):

Исходя из комментариев, как я понял, `std::hash` для строк будет использовать алгоритм хэширования `MurmurHashUnaligned2`. Для обычных же чисел как такового алгоритма и не будет - результатом будет непосредственно само число. Поэтому однозначно в случае с числами `std::hash` заведомо будет быстрее, чем `crc32` и без коллизий в принципе. А вот со строками несколько иная ситуация. Поэтому догадываюсь, что интересно сравнение `MurmurHashUnaligned2` и `crc32`. Думаю, что исходя из того, что результатом вычислений обоих алгоритмов является число одинаковой разрядности (как это указано в вопросе), то и вероятность коллизий будет примерно равна. В целом же неплохое сравнение алгоритмов по скорости и коллизиям для разных типов данных можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.strchr.com/hash_functions#results). В тесте присутствует и `crc32` и `murmur2`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ну во как то судя по тестам, приведенным также еще и strangeqargo получается, что `murmurhash2` быстрее `crc32`, но проигрывает по числу коллизий. Мне всегда казалось, что алгоритм хэширования уж по чему, а по количеству коллизий должна бы быть лучше, чем контролька :(

Comment: приоритеты для стандартной библиотеки, думаю были: скорость/память/коллизии. не знаю, почему комитет так решил, но, наверное, у них были соображения и, наверное, можно даже найти причины

Comment: @strangeqargo ну дык тут и к гадалке не ходи :) Ясный пень, что для стандарта исходили из каких-то своих соображений. И судя по тестам, явно коллизии были "не в почете". Скорее скорость и память. Для crc32 только сгенеренная таблица съест килобайт.